# Is there a more formal way to write "get away from"?

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms, formal-language

Actually, I am writing an article about machine learning which is a domain of computer science, and I want to tell this :

> If we change locations of data points, some of them get closer to the mean point, and the others **get away from** the mean point."

However, the phrase "get away from" seems to be not suitable for an article. It is very informal. In fact, I cannot both find a new phrase instead of it and change the structure of the sentence.

Can anyone tell me its synonym if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

> If we change locations of data points, some of them get closer to the mean point, and the others **get further away** from the mean point.

The phrase "get further away" is not informal and would be suitable for publication in an article.